# Accidently flushed iptables - restore

Tags: 16.04, dns, iptables

Im running ubuntu 16.04 and i have accidently flushed my iptables while trying to troubleshoot a slow internet issue. I used following command

```
iptables -F
```

Now i cannot open any website, log into skype, or even ping any website using url.

**I can ping internet ip addresses though, can open websites using their ip address, and can see ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED in chrome when i try to use url**.

I have tried fixes listed in following answer https://serverfault.com/questions/497438/how-to-reset-ubuntu-12-04-iptables-to-default-without-locking-oneself-out but it didnt fix the issue. The exact commands that i ren are as follows

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

iptables -F INPUT
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -F FORWARD
```

You can say that im not exactly sure what im doing since im not a server admin or a networking guy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**Update 1**
Since it appears to be DNS related, I just went ahead and added my ISP's DNS server's address in network connection settings `IPV4 Settings > DNS Servers` input box, restarted the machine, and it has come back to life. The internet appears to be working fine now.

I think I've found a way *around* the problem but the original problem is still there. Is it?

**Update 2**
I'm having another internet related issue (the original speed issue) that I've put the description of into another question. The question is here [Routing tables - Default gateway and traceroute discrepancy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820053/routing-tables-default-gateway-and-traceroute-discrepancy)

Comment: I'm pretty sure flushing is what resets `iptables`, and I'm also fairly certain that rebooting will restore it to defaults. Try that.

Comment: I have reset multiple times. It doesnt seem to affect this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You might have default policies in your iptables which drop each packet by default. Default policies won't get flushed. It would be of help if you post your iptables using

```
iptables -nvL
```

So making the iptables accept any input and output should prevent the loss of packets.

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Comment: I did that and it doesn't appear to be making any difference. I'm still getting DNS error. Please see the update in my question.

Comment: If there weren't any DNS Servers, like Google's 8.8.8.8, defined, then your machine wasn't able to resolve any domains.

Comment: Makes sense but there should be a default DNS server value (like it would use default gateway as a DNS server as well, honest question)? I do not remember putting in DNS server address manually in the past.

Comment: Well, that depends on your local network and its configuration.