# Routing tables - Default gateway and traceroute discrepancy

Tags: 16.04, internet, gateway, traceroute

I'm using 16.04 and having a discrepancy that appears to be slowing down the internet access for my machine.

I'm on a PC and connecting to internet using a USB WIFI device instead of the ethernet port present on the motherboard.

IP address of my internet gateway is `192.168.1.1`  (one I use to access router config screen)

IP address of the wifi interface is `192.168.1.21`

I'm using `DHCP` to obtain the ip address of both (wired and wifi) interfaces (I can include output of `ifconfig` if required. Omitted to keep the question relatively short)

The result of `netstat -nr` command is as follows

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.2     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlxec086b08251b
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlxec086b08251b
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlxec086b08251b
```

And output of `traceroute -n askubuntu.com` command is as follows

```
ejaz@ejaz-i5:~$ traceroute -n askubuntu.com
traceroute to askubuntu.com (151.101.129.69), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.2  3.297 ms  4.386 ms  5.111 ms
 2  * * *
 3  10.6.0.205  34.579 ms  40.183 ms  42.802 ms
 4  * * *
 5  xxx.xxx.xx.xxx  40.704 ms  41.341 ms  43.437 ms
 6  xxx.xxx.xx.xxx  44.187 ms  42.549 ms  42.612 ms
 7  10.0.3.182  42.607 ms  18.529 ms  27.290 ms
 8  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  43.253 ms  33.357 ms  40.347 ms
 9  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  60.037 ms  69.855 ms  57.101 ms
10  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  68.677 ms xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  67.130 ms xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  48.943 ms
11  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  55.302 ms  53.171 ms  56.792 ms
12  195.22.198.206  158.724 ms  166.306 ms  184.680 ms
13  195.22.205.153  189.038 ms  178.890 ms 195.22.196.215  182.389 ms
14  93.186.128.157  180.999 ms  175.675 ms  167.954 ms
15  129.250.2.50  186.880 ms  189.032 ms  183.655 ms
16  129.250.2.113  195.188 ms 129.250.2.211  205.249 ms  205.641 ms
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

*`xxx.xxx.xx.xxx` contain proper IP addresses in the actual output*

**Problem**

I think that the presence of `192.168.1.2` in the routing tables and in output of `traceroute` represents a problem because I do not have anything on the network having this address (100% loss on `ping`). I only have couple of PC's and some phones on this home network.

Also I think that **every** traceroute (and internet traffic) request starting with trying to communicate with `192.168.1.2` and timing out is slowing down the internet speed on this computer.

**Attempted solutions**
I tried replacing the wrong default gateway with what I think is right by using following commands

```
$ sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1

$ sudo route del default gw 192.168.1.2
```

The output of `netstat -nr` changed to exhibit the correct gateway then but the `traceroute` still makes request to `192.168.1.2`. Does this mean that the routing configuration is being picked from somewhere else? I'm not using static IP addresses.

Also, the default gateway resets to `192.168.1.2` after I reboot the system.

Can somebody please sort it out? Or shed some light on the situation.

**Additional questions**
1. Do the `ms` values in `traceroute` output appear to be that of a properly functioning `4G` internet connection?
2. What do the `* * *` from line 17 to 30 represent in `traceroute` output?

Thanks a lot for reading through the question.

**Update 1**

Following is `nmap` output as required by @stevieb

```
ejaz@ejaz-i5:/var/lib/dhcp$ sudo nmap -sS -P0 -O 192.168.1.2

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx xxx
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.2
Host is up (0.020s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
23/tcp  open     telnet
53/tcp  open     domain
80/tcp  filtered http
139/tcp open     netbios-ssn
445/tcp open     microsoft-ds
MAC Address: 8C:44:35:0A:34:62 (Shanghai BroadMobi Communication Technology)
Device type: general purpose
Running: Linux 2.6.X|3.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.6 cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3
OS details: Linux 2.6.32 - 3.5
Network Distance: 1 hop

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 9.82 seconds
```

and following is `ip addr show` output

```
ejaz@ejaz-i5:/var/lib/dhcp$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp5s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:ae:c5:bc:d7:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlxec086b08251b: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ec:08:6b:08:25:1b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.21/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlxec086b08251b
       valid_lft 70411sec preferred_lft 70411sec
    inet6 fe80::c4ed:f502:38f0:6481/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Update 2**

I'm seeing two `Ethernet network() Device not managed` errors in my network manager menu as well. I'm not sure when did these two entries start appearing.

[image]

**Update 3**

I did some more research and figured out that these two interfaces were created by VMWare Player software that I recently installed.

Comment: It appears as though your 192.x.x.x network is behind another private network (or the ISP has things poorly configured). Do you see the same `traceroute` results when connected via Ethernet cable? While on WIFI, can you connect to `192.168.1.1`'s web GUI? While on WIFI, do you see a DHCP lease for the PC (with the correct assigned IP) in the gateway's lease table? In essence, you need to figure out if you're connecting to the gateway device you think you are.

Comment: @stevieb I can ping my presumed correct gateway `192.168.1.1` and connect to its web ui using `http://192.168.1.1` in my browser. Checking `DHCP` settings on the gateway, I find no lease for `192.168.1.2`. In fact the funny thing is that the lease start IP address is `192.168.1.20` in the `DHCP` settings. Regarding `traceroute` using wired connection, I'm sorry I have no wired internet in place atm. I've a router though.

Comment: Sounds like you're getting a DHCP lease from a different (possibly rogue) DHCP server. What does `cat /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases` say as far as the `dhcp-server-identifier`? (the file may be located in `/var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient.leases` if it's not at the former location). Assuming you don't know what `192.168.1.2` is, `sudo apt-get install nmap`, then `sudo nmap -sS -P0 -O 192.168.1.2`, and update your question with this info.

Comment: Also, as I mentioned earlier, what happens when you disable wifi and connect to the network via Ethernet cable? Do you get a lease from `192.168.1.1`? Do the traceroutes look 'normal'?

Comment: @stevieb Thanks for your comments. I've added the details in the question. Regarding wired ethernet, I've answered that question in my previous comment "Regarding traceroute using wired connection, I'm sorry I have no wired internet in place atm. I've a router though."

Comment: @stevieb I can find the `/var/lib/dhcp/` directory but no `dhclient.leases` file in it.

Comment: Can you web to `192.168.1.2`? If you set your IP to static and set the gateway to `192.168.1.1`, does the trace change? fyi, `***` in a trace could mean many things... most often, that the device that you're hopping over has certain `ICMP` functionality firewalled, and the response is timing out. What prompt do you see when you `telnet 192.168.1.2`? Do you happen to have a *nix box on your network with Samba installed that inadvertently has a DHCP server running?

Comment: Ok, I cannot access `192.168.1.2` in browser. Setting a static IP and gateway changes the gateway in kernel routing table to `192.168.1.1`. But `traceroute` still goes to `192.168.1.2`. Telnet to `192.168.1.2` gives me a login prompt. And I do not have any *nix system running on same network. But the word `samba` rings a bell because there is a **checked** checkbox in my router/gateway config labeled `Samba`. P.S. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What model/brand of gateway is it?

Comment: It appears to be a de/re branded version of Huawei E5770 Mobile Broadband device. It uses a 4G SIM Card. Following product is the closest to what I could find quickly http://consumer.huawei.com/en/mobile-broadband/mobile-wifi/features/e5770-en.htm

Comment: @stevieb btw, I'm also using PureVpn (OpenVPN)

Comment: @stevieb I've added some more information to the question that might be relevant to the problem.

Comment: Is there any solution?